# Defining Polymer element after importing ES6 code via System.js

Tags: javascript, polymer, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I'm creating an HTML element using Polymer, and I want it to be able to work with an ES6 class I've written. Therefore, I need to import the class first and then register the element, which is what I do:

```
(function() {
  System.import('/js/FoobarModel.js').then(function(m) {
    window.FoobarModel = m.default;

    window.FoobarItem = Polymer({
      is: 'foobar-item',
      properties: {
        model: Object // instanceof FoobarModel === true
      },
      // ... methods using model and FoobarModel
    });
  });
})();
```

And it works well. But now I want to write a test HTML page to display my component with some dummy data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/system.js/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        map:{
          traceur: '/bower_components/traceur/traceur.min.js'
        }
      });
    </script>
    <link rel="import" href="/html/foobar-item.html">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      (function() {
        var data = window.data = [
          {
            city: {
              name: 'Foobar City'
            },
            date: new Date('2012-02-25')
          }
        ];
        var view;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          view = new FoobarItem();

          view.model = data[i];

          document.body.appendChild(view);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which isn't working for one simple reason: the code in the `<script>` tag is executed *before* Polymer registers the element.

Thus I'd like to know if there's a way to load the ES6 module **synchronously** using System.js or even better, if it's possible to listen to a JavaScript event for the element registration (something like `PolymerElementsRegistered`)?

I've tried the following without success:

- `window.addEventListener('HTMLImportsLoaded', ...)`
- `window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', ...)`
- `HTMLImports.whenReady(...)`

Answer (score 1):

In the `app/scripts/app.js` script from the **polymer starter kit**, they use [auto-binding template](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82LfXCeuaOo) and `dom-change` event

```
// Grab a reference to our auto-binding template
var app = document.querySelector('#app');

// Listen for template bound event to know when bindings
// have resolved and content has been stamped to the page
app.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
  console.log('Our app is ready to rock!');
});
```

Also check this [thread](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1381) gives alternatives to the `polymer-ready` event.